# Set Class's Variable Using Method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I make this simple program :

```
class Enemy(object):
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
        return name

    def set_health(self, health):
        self.health = health
        return health

Orc = Enemy()
Orc.set_name('Orc')
Orc.set_health(76)
```

I understand this is working but I wonder what's the difference between this and using `__init__` instead ? for example I made this similar program :

```
class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def name(self):
        return self.name

    def _health(self, health):
        self.health = health
        return self.health

Orc = Enemy('Orc')
Orc._health(85)
print(Orc._health)
print(Orc.name)
```

but I got this on output :

```
<bound method Enemy._health of <__main__.Enemy object at 0x00ED1670>>
Orc
```

What i'm trying to say is this `__init__` method do something important for example when I'm making a game ? maybe if I use `__init__` method I can load my Classes early before it is used later inside the game ?

Comment: `Orc._health` is a method. If you `print(Orc._health)`, you're not calling the method, just printing it, and `print` correctly tells you "It's a method called `_health`". If you wanted to print the `health` variable, you should have put `print(Orc.health)`

Comment: @khelwood ooh I okay, I thought that was an error. so if I do `print(Orc.health)` it's the same even without using `__init__` ?

Comment: Yes, `_health()` is the function to set the health, but `health` is the variable that has the value in it. @Wowotek

Comment: Oh and your `def name(self): return self.name` is invalid, you shouldn't define such function, you can just access the name like so: `print(Orc.name)` after setting `name` in `__init__`

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I see, so way to set Health is using a method and `__init__` method is used when I make an Object from Class. is there any way to use `__init__` method and then set variable? or i need to make another function ?

Comment: Why do you need another function? You can just do `Orc.health = 12` to set `Orc` enemy's `health`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting such a weird output is because `_health` is the method in your class, while `health` (without `_`) is the variable that holds the value. You're printing out `_health`, and printing out methods looks weird. You probably meant to print `health` instead.

---

However, you should not create setter and getter methods like this in the first place, but instead use the attributes as-is. All attributes should be set in the `__init__` method, which is called when the object is created. This makes sure the object has all of its attributes at all times after being created (you're free to initialize any attribute's value to `None`).

Here's an example how I'd do your program:

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
```

And now you can access the `name` and `health` attributes of your enemies easily without any extra hassle of methods:

```
>>> orc = Enemy('My Orc', 100)
>>> print(orc.name)
'My Orc'
>>> orc.health -= 30  # Deal 30 damage
>>> print(orc.health)
70
```

If you ever need to hide this stuff away, for example to make the `name` "private" so that it cannot be changed after creating the object, you can mark these attributes "private" by using a leading underscore:

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self._name = name  # "private" variable which can't be changed
        self.health = health
```

This doesn't make it really private, you can still access it through `orc._name`, but a leading underscore signals others that they should not go changing these variables on their own, and it might cause issues. Anything with leading underscore shouldn't be touched outside of the class.

But another problem arises. If we aren't allowed to touch `_name` outside of the class, how do we print out the name? This is where you create a function like you did earlier:

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self._name = name
        self.health = health

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name
```

Now you can get the name easily with this method:

```
>>> orc = Enemy('test', 0)
>>> print(orc.get_name())
test
```

But there's even a better way. See how ugly and inconsistent it is that sometimes you need to write `orc.health` and sometimes `orc.get_name()`? This is why Python has a built-in `property` functionality! This allows you to create getter/setter methods for these attributes, while keeping the syntax of an attribute! Let's see how it works for getter:

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self._name = name
        self.health = health

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
```

Now when we access `orc.name`, since it's marked as a property, it will automatically be called right away without the need for parenthesis:

```
>>> orc = Enemy('orcy', 12)
>>> orc.name  # calls the name() function automatically
'orcy'
```

We can even create a custom setter function, so that when you do `orc.name = 5`, it will secretly call `orc.name.setter(5)`:

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self._name = name
        self.health = health

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, string):  # Don't allow numbers, lists, etc.
            raise ValueError('Invalid name!')
        self._name = value
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
>>> orc = Enemy('Test', 1)
>>> orc.name
'Test'
>>> orc.name = 'Hmm'
>>> orc.name
'Hmm'
>>> orc.name = []
ValueError: Invalid name!
>>> orc.name
'Hmm'
>>> orc.name = 123
ValueError: Invalid name!
```

Comment: Whoa i just make a comment before, and this pop up. ok i get this, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Wowotek I added a quick explanation on properties, you might wanna read more about them, since they're a bit hard to get at first. But once you learn to use them, they're super awesome

Comment: this look like a documentation but better, hahaha. so what you saying is, even the `_name` is private i can still change it with `@name.setter` ? so what's the point using private/protected variable ? my PyCharm recommend `@staticmethod` instead ? is this a problem ?

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options, use a constructor(you give at the time you create the object the values health and name) or you use a setter( which means name and health could change its values after the creation of the object...
now, this:

```
print(Orc._health)
```

is printing the method and not the field/member of the class

that is why you get `<bound method Enemy._health of <__main__.Enemy object at 0x00ED1670>>`

Comment: This should definitely be a comment.

Comment: Feel free to. I didn't downvote, for what it's worth